# Java EE - Splitting web and business tiers over different servers

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, n-tier-architecture

We are debating the pros and contras of splitting tiers of java EE apps over multiple servers

To clarify: Suppose I have a Java EE app with a .war web layer and an EJB .jar business layer. They communicate via RMI

- One method of deployment is deploying the .war in one .ear on one application server, and the business layer in another .ear on another application server. Let's call this the **'split'** deployment model
- Another method is packaging the .war and the .jar in the same .ear, and deploying this .ear in one application server. Let's call this the **'together'** deployment model.

Pros named for the split model:

- forces complete split, so is a good preparation for a service oriented architecture
- Follows the Oracle Fusion Middleware High Availability Framework (See e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/core.1111/e10106/img/ashia158.gif)
- Scalability and reusablity (see discussion below)

Pros named for the together model:

- ease of deployment and administration
- better performance
- ease of load balancing

Both sides claim to be better for:

- Easy monitoring and capacity management
- ease of troubleshooting

What are your thoughts and experiences for both models?  You might detect my personal bias for one side in this post, but I'd like to hear honest arguments in either way.

Comment: You could consider `scalability` and `reusability` as pros for split deployment model.

Comment: In both cases I see not much difference either way: For **scalability**, a load balancer can adress multiple servers, so it seems to me to scale the same if you have 2 business and 2 web servers in split, or 4 generic servers in together.  For **reusability**, you can, if need arises, call the business layer via RMI while skipping the web layer, or even better, create a real web service

Comment: Regarding `scalability`, we could do scaling only in web layer say 4 webservers and 2 app servers which is ideal in enterprise world since we will do caching in webserver and expects more number of webserver instances that app server. My argument regarding `reusability` is that if you need business logic alone in a different product on top of same schema, you could just contact appserver instead of going through the complete stack. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In our specific situation, those arguments don't really apply: There is a caching server in front of the app servers for the static content, and an app server already allows you to skip parts of the stack by directly calling the business layer already.   However, other people will have other situations, so I added them as pros for split as you suggested.

Comment: Is your ejb being consumed/will be consumed by multiple applications, ie other than one war component you are mentioning. If not i dont see a strong argument for split.